# How to get subtotal from order items collection in magento 1.9.2 community edition

Tags: magento-1.9, php, orders, collection, ce-1.9.0.1

I am trying to show order details on frontend just like backend 
[image]

Here is my code

```
$orderData = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
$itemCollection = $orderData->getItemsCollection();

foreach($itemsCollection as $_items) {
    echo $_items->getName();
    echo $_items->getStatus();
    echo $_items->getOriginalPrice();
    echo $_items->getPrice();
    echo $_items->getQtyOrdered();
    echo $_items->getSubTotal();
    echo $_items->getTaxAmount();
    echo $_items->getPercent();
    echo $_items->getDiscountAmount();
    echo $_items->getRowTotal();
}
```

Apart from Subtotal I am getting Everything I tried this too:

```
echo $_items->getBaseSubtotal();
```

But I am still getting null value.
Any help will be appreciable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**base_subtotal** is ***field of Order table***.

it is not ***field to sales order item table.***.So you did not get data from  `$_items->getBaseSubtotal()`

In order to get a sales item base total try below code:

> ```
>   $items->getBaseRowTotal();
> ```

Comment: sir what about getSubtotal()

Comment: Prashant, getSubtotal()  give u you order 's subtotal in Order placed currency

Comment: Thanks a lot for the sharing the concept I got confused when I saw the collection using var_dump I thought this sub total is for item row , Your code worked for me

Comment: @AmitBera I have to give free shipping order over and 1000 and zipcode between 600001 to 600010, i am using webshop matrix rate for shipping method, in this case, shopping cart pricing rule not working free shipping, so i have to plan for do custom PHP code for giving free shipping, My condition how can i give condition like subtotal is equal or greated than 1000 and zipcode 600001 and 600010 in /public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml

Answer (score 0):

From order items collections, you can get item's (row's) `subtotal` OR `row_total` BUT you **CAN NOT** get Order's Subtotal. You can iterate through order item's collection and can sum `$_items->getSubTotal();` but it's **NOT RECOMMENDED**.

For Order's subtotal, use :

```
echo "Subtotal: ".$orderData->getSubtotal();
```